# 404 error on WebApi call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angular, asp.net-web-api, web-config

I'm facing a tricky situation where I have a angular2 app that deploys to the server all fine but when making a request call to the WebApi server I get 404 errors in response. The WebApi calls work fine in the local enviroment but on the live server it fails.

```
<!--Redirect selected traffic to index -->
    <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="/api/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
```

Above is the rule I have placed in the Web.config file where the WebApi server will only be invoked if there is "/api/" in the URL. I have an anonymous action in the controller that I would expect to be invoked when running via postman but I just get a 404 error in response.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/dashboard/getanon")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTaskItemsAnon()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { response = "Hello: Anon" });
    }
```

The webapp is hosted under a subdomain within the network. All angular2 files are loaded correctly I ham presented with the login screen but cannot make communication with the WebApi controllers. Any help would be appreciated thanx.

**UPDATE:** 
Below is the WebApiConfig.cs file

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the snapshot of Postman how you are making the API call? Also, can you try removing the [AllowAnonymous] attribute from your Action method and try?

Comment: I have removed the [AllowAnonymous] and nothing has changed. With Postman I am simply using a normal GET request with no parameters to the appropriate URL. I know it is right in Postman because under localhost environment Postman successfully reaches the WebApi action in the controller.

Comment: Can you post the code in your RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: I dont have a RouteConfig.cs I have a WebApiConfig.cs file as I am using WebApi as the server. See update for WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Can you change: from- routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}" to- routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" in WebApiConfig.cs and try again?

Comment: Still not working. If I'm not mistaken the default route in the webapiconfig is just there as a fall back.

Comment: Yeah. But it seems your request URL format is different (contains action name) than the one you have in the WebApiConfig.cs. Is GetTaskItemsAnon() a present inside the WebAPI Controller or an MVC Controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132393/discussion-between-souvik-ghosh-and-rossco).

Answer (score 0):

WebApi has some rules to match controller methods (name, parameter) with incoming requests. 
I guess here WebApi might expects a parameter for getting a record by an ID. Your are using GET which implicitly needs an "id" for getting a records.

For testing purposes, try

1) to use a parameter in your method.
     public IHttpActionResult GetTaskItemsAnon(int id = 1)

2) remove the [httpget] directive for your method
   and take care there are no conflicts with other methods in your controller class